# Help with Connecting to SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sql-developer, network

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer. I was able to get the SQL Server JDBC installed on SQL Developer and am able to see the SQL server Tab on the Connections page. I have SQL server running on the machine with 4 Databases that I am wanting to connect. When I try to connect though I am getting a "Failure - Cannot Connect with Microsoft SQL server on Localhost". I have not changed any defaults when installing SQL Server . Any Help appreciated.

[image: SQL Developer Connection Info]

Comment: Are you connecting to named instance?  under instance use "INSTANCENAME" and Port = '1433' (if it's default, otherwise change it accordingly)

Comment: The port was 1434 , Got it from the USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' 
GO  SQL query. Now I am getting the following " Error Status : Failure -I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property" I did try to copy the ntlmauth.dll from the SSO directory and paste it in the JRE/bin/ folder but am still getting that error.

Comment: copy the system-specific "ntlmauth.dll" into any other Java install folders (i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)). Have you done this? If Yes, you may not seeing this error message again.

Comment: So I did copy the ntlmauth.dll to the jre folders and as a last resort tried copying them to the C:\Program Files\System 32 folder and restarted the machine and that worked! I am able to connect now